# Entities loaded in a one session are not cached

Tags: nhibernate, caching

There are two entities of static data (need to be fully loaded in memory)

```
[Class(...)]
public class AttributeInfo : EntityBase
{
    [Id(0, Name = "Id", Column = "id", Type = "int")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public AttributeInfo () {}

}

[Class(...)]
public class Item : EntityBase
{
    [Id(0, Name = "Id", Column = "id", Type = "int")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(Name = "...", Column = "...", Lazy = Laziness.False)]
    public virtual AttributeInfo Attrs { set; get; }

    public Item() { }
}
```

I open the session and start the transaction:

```
   using (var s = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
   using (var tr = s.BeginTransaction())
   {
```

I load all attributes:

```
   s.CreateCriteria< AttributeInfo>().List().Cast< AttributeInfo>().ToArray()
```

And all items:

```
   s.CreateCriteria< Item>().List().Cast< Item>().ToArray()
```

The problem is that cache is not used and for every item nhibernate creates a select from AttributeInfo query.

I understand that there is no big value of optimization of static data loading. But I want to understand how nhibernate cache works.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your example works for me without nh generating a query for each attribute. Only if I do not load all attributes, the second query of course will load all attributes one by one because of the not lazy setting in your mapping.

Maybe you are using an old version of nh or have some other settings somewhere else?

Anyways, the best way to do that is to define the fetch mode for the not lazy collection.

```
 [ManyToOne(Lazy = Laziness.False, Fetch=FetchMode.Join)]
```

This will enforce nh to create a join over attributes query which in fact resolves the item + attributes in one go. With this solution you do not have to (pre)load all attributes, even those you might not need...

Hint:

To watch the elements present in the first level cache you can use a simple extension

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FirstLevelCache<T>(this ISession session)
    {
        ISessionImplementor impl = session.GetSessionImplementation();
        IPersistenceContext pc = impl.PersistenceContext;

        foreach (Object key in pc.EntityEntries.Keys)
        {
            if (key is T)
            {
                yield return ((T) key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now

```
var attributes = session.CreateCriteria<AttributeInfo>().List().Cast<AttributeInfo>().ToArray();

var cached = session.FirstLevelCache<AttributeInfo>().ToList();
```

`cached` should contain the attributes.